# PHP Session Variable: Error Undefined Variable

Tags: php, html, variables, undefined

So basically its creating a session using the users email and password. Checking whether it has an email and password entered and if not redirecting them back to the login page. Hence:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'connect.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || !isset($_SESSION['password']))
    {
        header("location:loginTemplate.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    }
?>
```

So I then want to use the $email variable to essentially welcome the users. Hence:

```
 <h2>Welcome <?php echo $email; ?></h2>
```

But I am getting an error saying the variable is undefined

Comment: There is not initialization or no any value in $email variable.

Comment: session_start(); must be placed before all html or output at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    header("location:loginTemplate.php");
}
else
{
     $email = $_SESSION['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `$email` anywhere.

Correct the line:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

To

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

You need to get `email` value from Session, and you are trying to assign value to session variable.

Thats it.

Comment: @user3667111, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution.

Comment: yeah sorry you answered too quickly it wouldn't let me haha :) good luck in the future man, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your logic to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password']))
```

Probably, your session was not set because you wasn't redirected to `loginTemplate.php`, so with `OR` option, it will fail to enter the desired condition but will work with `&&` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway man, not quite what  I was looking for but cheer:)